# Why my products are empty with this function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

In the console it shows me a warning:
The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your own `selectId` implementation. The entity that was passed: (2) [{…}, {…}] The `selectId` implementation: item => item._id.
What am I missing?

I try to call the productos with:

```
const products = useSelector(productSelectors.selectIds)
```

```
import { createSlice, createEntityAdapter, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

//Fetch the businesses to show in the home page
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  'products/fetchProducts',
  async (id, { dispatch }) => {
    return axios.get(`https://api-test-carrinho.herokuapp.com/product/business/${id}`
    ).then(resp => {
      dispatch(addProducts(resp.data))
    })
  }
)

const productsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (item) => item._id
});

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: productsAdapter.getInitialState({ loading: false }),
  reducers: {
    /* addProduct: productsAdapter.addOne, */
    addProducts: productsAdapter.setAll
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchProducts.pending](state){
      state.loading = true
    },
    [fetchProducts.fulfilled](state, { payload }){
      state.loading = false
      productsAdapter.setAll(state, payload)
    }
  }
});

export default productsSlice.reducer;

export const { /* addProduct,  */addProducts } = productsSlice.actions;

export const productSelectors = productsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.products
);

export const {
  selectById: selectProductById,
  selectAll: selectAllProducts
} = productSelectors;
```

Comment: Is productSelectors.selectIds defined?  I see selectById, selectId but no sign of selectIds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Undefined id

I was able to replicate your error message

> The entity passed to the `selectId` implementation returned undefined.

On the first instance of the error what I'm seeing in the console is an array of three products.  It is trying to find the `._id` property *on that array*.  It thinks the `array` is a single entity rather than an array of entities.  Then it is trying to find the `._id` property on numbers like `3` and `0`.

What's happening here is that it is treating [your response](https://api-test-carrinho.herokuapp.com/product/business/609ee7c9daf43e472de400e4) as dictionary of product objects which it isn't. We need to be looking at just the `.data` property and that's where we'll find the products.

Now this is where it gets confusing, but you actually need `resp.data.data` instead of `resp.data`.  An `axios` response has a `.data` property which contains the JSON.  Then inside your JSON you have your own `.data` property.

#### Thunk Issues

After I fix that, the products get successfully added to the state by `addProducts`.  But there is still a problem further down in `fetchProducts.fulfilled`.  You will get an error

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Because the `payload` of your fulfilled action is `undefined`.

With `createAsyncThunk` you actually don't need to `dispatch` anything from the thunk.  What you need to do is `return` the data that you want to have as the `payload` of your `fetchProducts.fulfilled` action.

```
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetchProducts",
  async (id) => {
    return axios
      .get(`https://api-test-carrinho.herokuapp.com/product/business/${id}`)
      .then((resp) => resp.data.data);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Linda Paist! You're the best ! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Redux Documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples), `useSelector` should be a function:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter)
  return <div>{counter}</div>
}
```

So, maybe this will help you:

```
const products = useSelector(state => state./* however your store is implemented */productSelectors.selectIds)
```

Comment: I can see why it's confusing but `productSelectors.selectIds` *is* a function.  `productSelectors` is a keyed object of selector functions. It's from [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#selector-functions)